# How to find the domain and range for the composition $g\circ f$, i.e. $g(f(x,t),t)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I have the following:

> \begin{align}
> \frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(x,t)&=g(f(x,t),t) \tag 1\\
> f(x,0)&= x \tag 2
> \end{align}
> where $g:\mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb R^n$

The domain and range for $f$ is not stated, but I assume $f:\mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb R^n$?

However, in the RHS we have a function composition of $g$ and $f$, i.e. $g\circ f$. But the composition is not valid if $f:\mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb R^n$ according to the definition (Wikipedia):

> The functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ are composed to yield a function... The resulting compositie function is denoted $g\circ f : X \rightarrow Z$, defined by $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$.

How can I "see" the domain and range for $f$ and $g\circ f$ from $(1)-(2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since domain of $g$ is $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$, this means the vector $(f(x,t), t)$ must be in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. Consequently, $f(x,t) \in \Bbb{R}^n$. So the co-domain for $f$ is $\Bbb{R}^{n}$. From the second equation given, we also get that $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$.

But observe that the input vector $(x,t)$ will now be in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Finally we can say that $f:\Bbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$.

The composition map $g \circ f$ is NOT defined. Note that $g(f(x,t), t)$ is NOT the composition of $g$ and $f$ because there is an extra argument $t$ in the input for $g$.

**Example**
Let $g:\Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be defined as $g(p,q,r)=(p+q,r)$ and let $f:\Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be defined as $f(a,b,c)=(a^2,b+c)$.

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$
\begin{align*}
g(f(\mathbf{x},t), t)&=g(f(x_1,x_2,t)\,, \,t )\\
&=g((x_1^2,x_2+t), \, \, t)\\
&=g(x_1^2,\,\, x_2+t,  \,\, t)\\
&=(x_1^2+x_2+t, \,\, t)
\end{align*}

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thanks! $g(f(x,t),t)$ "looks" like a composition but is not according to the definition. So it is not a composition, but is there a proper name for $g(f(x,t),t)$? 

I often have this problem in other examples. For instance (an ODE), if $ y'(t) = h(y(t),t)$, where $y : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $h:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. So the function (the derivative) is $y':\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (i.e. $h(y(t),t)$) and "looks" like a composition but is not. Right?

Comment: @JDoeDoe Yes $h(y(t), t)$ is not a composition of $h$ and $y$.

Comment: Hi @AnuragA ! Your example: Isn't $g$ actually a composition of another function, say, $F:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$, so $h=g\circ F:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Donsert I'm not sure if I get the point you are trying to make. Yes $g$ can be a composition of some functions. But OP's question is about the $g$ and $f$ that OP is using in the problem and is asking if $g(f,t)$ can be viewed as a composition of *this* $f$ and $g$

Comment: Hi! I will try to reformulate my question. Check JDoeDoe's comment. $h(y(t),t)$ is not a valid composition of $h$ and $y$. But, can't we create a composition $p$ by introducing $Y:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$, defined by $Y(t)=(y(t),t)$? And we end up with $p(t) = (h \circ Y)(t)=h(Y(t))=h(y(t),t)$, where we have the composition $p: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$? So $p$ is a composition of $h$ and $Y$ (not $y$). From JDoeDoe's comment I used $p$ instead of $y'$.

Comment: @AnuragA Feel free to correct me if my composition $p$ was wrong. I was curious if we could use the same method in your example.

Comment: @Donsert That would work.